# How to remove special characters from a string before specific character?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, special-characters, str-replace

I have a `df` that has a column called `EMAIL`, which contains various email addresses. I want to remove all the special characters, specifically ., -, and _ that come before @ and append a new column `NEW_EMAIL`.  For example, if `df['EMAIL'] = 'ab_cd_123@email.com'`, I want `df['NEW_EMAIL'] = 'abcd123@email.com'`.

I was able to remove periods successfully with my codes below, but cannot seem to remove underscore or dash in the same line of code. Right now, I am repeating the same line of codes to remove those three special characters, which is quite ugly. Can someone lend me a hand please? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
df['NEW_EMAIL'] = df.EMAIL.str.replace(r'\.(?!.{1,4}$)','', regex = True)
df['NEW_EMAIL'] = df.NEW_EMAIL.str.replace(r'\.(?!.{1,4}$)','', regex = True)
df['NEW_EMAIL'] = df.NEW_EMAIL.str.replace(r'\.(?!.{1,4}$)','', regex = True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['NEW_EMAIL'] = df['EMAIL'].str.replace(r'[._-](?=[^@]*@)', '', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBjOvF/1). *Details*:

- `[._-]` - a `.`, `_` or `-` char
- `(?=[^@]*@)` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of any zero or more chars other than `@` and then a `@` char immediately to the right of the current location.

**If you need to replace/remove any special char**, you should use

```py
df['NEW_EMAIL'] = df['EMAIL'].str.replace(r'[\W_](?=[^@]*@)', '', regex=True)
```

See a Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'EMAIL':['ab_cd_123@email.com', 'ab_cd.12-3@email.com']})
>>> df['EMAIL'].str.replace(r'[._-](?=[^@]*@)', '', regex=True)
0    abcd123@email.com
1    abcd123@email.com
Name: EMAIL, dtype: object
```

Comment: @casi_cielo32 Just in case you want to remove any special char there, replace `[._-]` with `[\W_]` in the pattern. I added this version to the answer as it might turn out useful for others.